# Dropdown of user roles that depend on variable

Tags: user-roles

I have a dropdown where the user can select if he will checkout for him or for his customer. When registered, he gets two roles : Partner,[his_company].

So i want to display a dropdown with  customers who have his role [his_company] but my code is not working.

```
<?php 

$billing_company =  get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_company', 
true );


$args = array(
    'role' => $billing_company  // string|array,
);

wp_dropdown_users($args);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1: `$billing_company` will return user billing_company whatever it is.
2: In `$args` you are supposed to put an array of user roles to fetch.

If you don't know user role then you can use global var `global $current_user;` and `$user_roles = $current_user->roles;` to get all current user roles, so it would be

```
$args = array(
   'role__in' => 'his_company';  // string|array,
);
```

Check if it works?

Comment: Still it shows all the users.

Comment: Updated answers check now if it works!?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
It was like this :

```
<?php 
$current_user=wp_get_current_user();


$args = array(
    'role' => $current_user->roles[1]  // string|array,
);

wp_dropdown_users($args);
 ?>
```